# set innerText on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, innertext

I have a little app that takes user input, and I want to show them a little preview as they type (exactly as Stackoverflow does it).

I try something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>{user_input}</div>,
  document.getElementById('preview')
);
```

It works great until I try to add a new line, react it ignores and just renders a white space. But if I do it on vanilla javascript:

```
var content = document.createElement('div');
content.innerText = user_input;
document.getElementById('preview').appendChild(content);
```

Doing it like this does the trick and every line break gets automatically turned into a `<br>` tag.

Is there a way to set innerText on react or should I just go with the vanilla solution?

Is there a setback in using innerText?

Comment: It sounds like all of your code isn't "inside" react components. In general, you should probably only have one `ReactDOM.render()` Here's a link to React's forms page https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html as well as a codepen example of showing a preview of a controlled component's value https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpOvVw

Answer (score 2):

using this is more suitable for keeping the indentation and line breaks:

```css
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

it not only keeps the line-break, but also maintains the spaces

so if you text has

```html
<span id="preview-message" style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
...   white space maintains between dots   ...
</span>
```

or

```html
<span id="preview-message" style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
  hello everyone...  
       spaces here will be maintain too 
  new line here will maintain too
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below may be what you need.

```
var user_inputs = ['line1', 'line2'];
var inputs = user_inputs.map(function(user_input, idx){
   return <div key={idx}>{user_input}</div>
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="root">{inputs}</div>,
  document.getElementById('preview')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the block in which the text is located, set the css rule:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

in your case:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div style={{white-space: pre-line}}>{user_input}</div>,
  document.getElementById('preview')
);
```